# Putting separate values to rows from a dictionary using a foreach loop

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to take the values I have parsed from a JSON file and convert them into rows.  I have tried all week, but still cannot figure this out.

---

My current output looks like this:

```
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
a: 1a
b: 2a
c: 3a
a: 1b
b: 2b
c: 3b
```

I want my output to be like this, but I cannot find a solution.

```
a   b   c 
1   2   3
1a  2a  3a
1b  2g  3b
```

---

Here's the kicker: I need to be able to write to the rows using a format similar to this:

---

```
   foreach (var item in MyStuff)
        {

        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1},{2}",
        item.a, item.b, item.c
         );
```

---

How can I do this?  Is this even possible?  I have been trying for days.

---

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = 
        @"{
            'somethingone': 'abc',
            'somethingtwo': 'abcde-1234',
            'information': 
            {
                'report': [
                     {
                        'a': '1',
                        'b': '2',
                        'c': '3'
                     },
                     {
                        'a': '1a',
                        'b': '2a',
                        'c': '3a'
                     },
                     {
                        'a': '1b',
                        'b': '2b',
                        'c': '3b'
                     },
                 ]
             }
        }";

        RootObj mainObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(json);

        Console.WriteLine("somethingone: " + mainObj.somethingone);
        Console.WriteLine("somethingtwo: " + mainObj.somethingtwo);

        foreach (Dictionary<string, string> report in mainObj.information.report)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in report)
            {
                string key = item.Key;
                string value = item.Value;

                Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + value);
            }
        }
    }
}

class RootObj
{
    public string somethingone { get; set; }
    public string somethingtwo { get; set; }
    public Information information { get; set; }
}

class Information
{
    public Dictionary<string, string>[] report { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I'm trying to hack something that works into something that is similar, I try to  imagine a set of steps in the evolution of the code. There might be too many changes for a single answer, so I'll suggest start at the first step. If you assume the JSON structure is going to be consistent, your output is *sort of* in the right stucture/order, but mostly need format changes. First you need to add a header that does the "a b c" part. Then you need to change the main output so it shows only the data, and then you want it to group the data into rows of three...

Answer (score 0):

You've got yourself most of the way there already, you just need to figure out how to pivot the structure.

This should get you started.

```
// define a format
var columnFormat = "{0,-4}";

// get the column names
var keys = mainObj.information.report.First().Keys.ToList();

// print the column headers
keys.ForEach(key => Console.Write(columnFormat, key));
Console.WriteLine();

// print the rows
foreach (var report in mainObj.information.report)
{
    keys.ForEach(key => Console.Write(columnFormat, report[key]));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This will work, but it's fragile. If you know the report part of your json will always contain entries with the exact same structure (same number of columns with the same names), then this will work.

But what if we mess with the columns in your report like this:

```
'report': [
        {
            'a': '1',
            'c': '3'
        },
        {
            'a': '1a',
            'b': '2a',
            'c': '3a',
            'd': '4a'
        },
        {
            'a': '1b',
            'b': '2b',
            'c': '3b'
        },
```

Now the above solution would break, so you need to be a little more flexible when getting your column names and values.

```
// get the column names
var keys = mainObj.information.report
              .SelectMany(x => x.Keys)
              .Distinct()
              .OrderBy(key => key)
              .ToList();

// print the column headers
keys.ForEach(key => Console.Write(columnFormat, key));
Console.WriteLine();

// print the rows
foreach (var report in mainObj.information.report)
{
    keys.ForEach(key =>
    {
        string value;
        report.TryGetValue(key, out value);

        Console.Write(columnFormat, value);
    });

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This should result in output like:

```
a   b   c   d
1       3
1a  2a  3a  4a
1b  2b  3b
```